# How to read a text file from a Class method

Tags: android

I want to use a Class method to read a text file & pass a return value.

My error is the line: 
`fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);`

> The error message is:
>   Cannot resolve method 'openFileInput(java.lang.String)'

I suspect it's because I'm not passing a context, or that Android does not know the full file path using my Class method code.

I want to use the Class method so I can call it from various Activities.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public static String GetUserId(){
    String str_return = null;
    String FILE_NAME = "userid.txt";

try {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);                     \\<-- error is here
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String text;

    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(text).append("\n");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `openFileInput` is Method of `ContextWrapper` which is only available with `Context` . So you need a context object to call this method ..

Comment: "So you need a context object to call this method" <- so is this something I pass to my Class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
File yourFile = new File("YOUR_TEXTFILE_PATH");
String data = null;
try (FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(yourFile)) {

FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

data = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();  //this is the data from your textfile
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And generating the textfile

```
 File root = new File("YOUR_FOLDER_PATH");
//File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName); //im using this
//creation of folder (if you want)
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }

    File gpxfile = new File(root, textFileName);
    FileWriter writer;
     writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(textFileData);

    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: This worked fine. Thanks! Now I need to save some data to my file so I can read it.

Comment: great!. Please upvote it too :). I also add a generation of text file. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks again.  I did upvote it, but stackoverflow won't display it because my reputation is still new.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in one of my kotlin project likethis, It might work in Java too.

```
val textFromFile = openFileInput(filePath).reader().readText()
```